# SQL advice needed

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I'm trying to sort users with duplicate emails. However I also want to be able to see the count:

```
select ju.id, ju.email
from jhi_user ju
where ju.email in (
    SELECT ju2.email
    FROM jhi_user ju2 
    GROUP BY ju2.email
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

I ordered them, so just having the count would be nice.

Comment: Please share the table structure, sample input data, the expected output, and all attempts you've tried.

Comment: Is it necessary? I only want to grab the count and have it displayed? Otherwise the sql query is working

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: There is no question in this post. PS Please do not post what you think is poor, write something you think is good. You can ask questions about asking at [meta]. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Please do not overstrike, make your presentation the best possible now. Past versions are at the 'edited' link.

Comment: Seems like when this is clear it will be a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Answer (score 2):

You can join instead of using `in`:

```
select e.id, e.email, d.cnt_dups
from ju.email e
inner join (select email, count(*) cnt_dups from ju.email having count(*) > 1) d 
    on d.email = e.email
order by e.email
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL > 8.0 you can use window functions, in this case `COUNT OVER`:

```
select ju.id, ju.email, ju.cnt from (
    select *,
           count(*) over (partition by email) cnt
    from jhi_user
) ju where cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can make out you're trying to find where the same e-mail address is being used for multiple user accounts.

Here is the list of such e-mail addresses.

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS UserAccounts
FROM jhi_user
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

You could then join this back on to the accounts table to get full account information.

```
SELECT u.email, u.id
FROM jhi_user u
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS UserAccounts
        FROM jhi_user
        GROUP BY email
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS d
        ON u.email = d.email
ORDER BY u.email, u.id
```